# How to reserve a MySQL row and update

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I was asked for a feature that I'm not sure how to accomplish.  Have a form page where a phone number is entered - I need to get that phone number into a row on a button submit, and in the same form about 5-10 minutes later fill out the rest of the options and update that same row.  Not sure how to do that.  I was thinking to use mysql_insert_id() / last_insert_id()..

">

```
<?php
$hostname = "*";
$username = "*";
$password = "*";
$EmpID = $_COOKIE["dsmkttrackerid"];
mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("*");
$sql="SELECT * FROM User WHERE EmpID='".$EmpID."'";
$r = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_affected_rows()==0){
}
else {
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($r);
   $NT_Login = $row['NT_Login']; 
   $Job = $row['Job']; 
   if ($Job == "MADMIN" || $Job == "ADMIN" || $Job == "MPLT") {
      $Pilot=true;
   }
}
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
$date = date("Y-m-d",time());
$time = date("H:i:s",time());
if ($_POST[Comment]) {
   $_POST[Comment] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[Comment]);
   $PHONE = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[PHONE]);
   //check if dup post, caused by refreshing page.
   $sql="Select * from Data where Comment='$_POST[Comment]'";
   if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql)) <1) {
      $sql="INSERT INTO Data(`Date`, `Time`, `EmpID`, `PHONE`, `Comment`, 
      `OrigMention`, `OrigSent`, `PostMention`, `Mod`, `Pilot`)
      VALUES('$date','$time','$_POST[EmpID]','$_POST[PHONE]','$_POST[Comment]',
      '$_POST[OrigMention]','$_POST[OrigSent]','$_POST[PostMention]',
      '$_POST[Mod]','$_POST[Pilot]')";
      if (!mysql_query($sql))
      {
          die('Please report this error to your supervisor: <br />'
             . mysql_error());
      }
      else {
         $Msg = "Post #".mysql_insert_id()." Tracked Successfully.";
      }
   }
   else {
      //if dup is found:
      $Msg ="Duplicate Entry Detected.";
   }
}
else {
   //if no post was sent to the server:
   $Msg ="";
}
?>
```

Comment: I tried, but I'm still having a little difficulty understand what you're asking. Are you saying that you want to submit the phone number and get back the id of the phone number row in the database without leaving the page?

Comment: Well, yes - I believe the method that would be best would be to submit the phone with the phone number, and then when the data is gathered to resubmit an update to that previous row with further detailed information.   Just getting there is confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

Get the ID using `mysql_insert_id()` as you've done.  Store it in the session, and you can reference it for the rest of the form.

Comment: I've never worked with sessions before - so after initial submit the session data would be stored like $_SESSION['mysql_insert_id()'] ?

Comment: no, like this: `$_SESSION['id'] = mysql_insert_id();` but note my answer, which is another way to do this without sessions. Although it's not the "most recommended" solution, it may work for you (especially if you've never worked with sessions before)

Comment: Make sure to use session_start() on every page where you need that session variable. I would use sessions for this type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

As tandu said, you can use `mysql_insert_id()` to get the id, then store it in the session, and reference it later.  I caution, however, if you use the default PHP sessions (via `session_start()` and `$_SESSION` and the like), the session will not exist forever, so it's possible, if they leave their computer and come back a few hours later (eg, coming back from lunch), the would have to start the process all over.

I think it's best to have your own session handlers (in my personal experience, this has proven to be more controllable, and secure anyway).  Another option, however, is to send the id back to the user as a hidden value in the form, such as:

```
<form ...>
    <input name="dbid" value="<?=$id?>" type="hidden" />
    <!-- the rest of the form.... -->
```

If you don't want to reveal the dbid to a potential malicious user, then this is out of the question.  And, strictly speaking, I think this is bad practice.  However, it is another option that works.

**EDIT:** Yet *another* option is to use [cookies](http://us.php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php)

Comment: The page is set to time out after an hour.  The beginning part wasn't hard for me, but this is stumping me - and I've never worked with PHP Sessions before - reading up on that now.

Comment: Yes to check out on sessions and cookies - it is good for you to know.  Have you tried the hidden form input?

Comment: Like this?  `$id = mysql_insert_id();
}?>
<form class="transform" name="tracker" id="tracker" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<input name="EmpID" id="EmpID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $EmpID ?>" />
<input name="row" value="<?=$id?>" type="hidden" />`

Comment: The next question I would haev then is how do I make sure the next phone number inserted into the database isn't overwriting the previous row, still?

Comment: Yes, then when the form gets sent to the server, `$_POST['row']` should have the id of the row inserted into the database.

Comment: I'll remind you this is *not* that secure, because a malicious user could modify the contents of that input, and you will get the incorrect id sent to the server.

Comment: Well, it's not on a public site.  But, wouldn't the form continue to auto-populate the same mysql_insert_id() # into the row field?  Don't want to overwrite the same row over and over in a loop..

Comment: If you use mysql_insert_id(), it will give you the last insert id.  Every time you need a new row, do the insert statement in sql, use mysql_insert_id() to get that (new) id, then pass that id to the form, and start using the id you get from the form.  Make sense?